# Unity partially broken after installing GNOME

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I recently installed GNOME on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but this appears to have damaged Unity such that I can't change the wallpaper in Unity, nor will the context menu appear when I right-click the desktop. The Launcher and everything else appears to work correctly, however. So what's the deal with my Unity desktop?